# Cryptography: Solve $x^2 \equiv 331 \pmod{385}$ using modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, legendre-symbol

How can I find (3) congruence equations to solve

$$x^2\equiv331\pmod{385}$$

using [Legendre and Jacobi Symbols](http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs467/2010s/handouts/ho07.pdf) and use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to combine the solutions to those equations to produce the solutions to $x^2\equiv331\pmod{385}$

*Solution*

$$385=5\cdot7\cdot11$$

$$\begin{align}
x^2&\equiv1\pmod5\\
x^2&\equiv2\pmod7\\
x^2&\equiv1\pmod{11}\\[10pt]
x&\equiv\{1,4\}\pmod5\\
x&\equiv\{3,4\}\pmod7\\
x&\equiv\{1,10\}\pmod{11}\\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
M1\implies&385/5=77\\
&77-1\pmod5=3\pmod5\\[5pt]
M2\implies&385/7=55\\
&55-1\pmod7=6\pmod7\\[5pt]
M2\implies&385/11=35\\
&35-1\pmod{11}=6\pmod{11}\\[5pt]
\end{align}$$

$$a=1,4;\quad b=3,4;\quad c=1,10$$

$$\begin{align}
x&\equiv a\cdot77\cdot3+b\cdot5\cdot6+c\cdot35\cdot6\\
&\equiv231a+330b+210c
\end{align}$$

Therefore
[Congruence of 8 cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cy0C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$385=5\cdot 7\cdot 11$

$$\begin{align}&x^2\equiv 1\pmod{5}\\ &x^2\equiv 2\pmod{7}\\ &x^2\equiv 1\pmod{11}\end{align}$$

$$\iff \begin{align}&x\equiv \{1,4\}\pmod{5}\\ &x\equiv \{3,4\}\pmod{7}\\ &x\equiv \{1,10\}\pmod{11}\end{align}$$

Now check $8$ cases and use Chinese Remainder Theorem for each case.

Comment: Won't it be x≡{2,5}(mod7)

Comment: No.  If $x \equiv \{2, 5\} \pmod{7}$, then $x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$.

Comment: @BrianTung How do you actually get {3,4}. Can you explain please?

Comment: Nevermind, understood. `2+7 =9 and sqrt is 3` 
`2+7+7=16 and sqrt is 4`

Comment: @user236182 can you please verify my solution. I have added it into the questions itself.

Comment: @nversusp Everything except the table is correct. In the table you mixed the values of $a,b,c$. It should be $a\in\{1,4\}, b\in\{3,4\},c\in\{1,10\}$, like you said in the question itself. So you got wrong answers there in the table.

Comment: Awesome. Now can the downvote to my question be removed. :). Thank you Sir!.

Comment: @nversusp But change the table. You got wrong answers there.

Comment: Corrected the image. Could not post the image, Since I need more than 10 reputation!! (But provided the link)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** $385 = 5 \times 7 \times 11$.  And if $x^2 \equiv 331 \pmod{385}$, then

$$
x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}
$$
$$
x^2 \equiv \,\,? \pmod{7}
$$
$$
x^2 \equiv \,\,? \pmod{11}
$$

Comment: I understand that is 2 & 1. But How do I prove congruence?

Comment: I would really appreciate your help?

Comment: Look at @user236182's answer, which takes the solution a little further.

Comment: I did. Won't it be  `x ≡ {2,5} (mod7)`. And now, do I have to compare these equations (1,2,1,1,4,2,5,1,10)

Comment: can you please verify my solution. I have added it into the questions itself.